# iOS app image sizes and naming conventions

Tags: ios, iphone

It's a first time I am posting iPhone app to Apple. After much research I have not been able to find out answer to my questions and I don't want my app to be bounced back due to a silly thing. Please note that my app is only for **iOS7**. Below are my questions:

1) Do I've to provide 2 images one in low resoltion and another in high resolution?

2) I've read that background image or launch image for iPhone5 should have resolution of 640 x 1136. The same for iPhone4 is 640 x 960. Is there any naming convention for such images (both for iPhone4 and iPhone5)?

3) What should be the resolution for application icons? The resolutions which I know are 1024 X 1024 (required for app store) and 120 x 120. On some links I've read about resolutions of 72px x 72px and 114px x 114px instead of 120 x 120.

Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you are only targeting retina devices (i.e. iOS 7 only on iPhones) you can provide only the 2x assets.

2) There's a naming convention for the launch image, which is

- `Default@2x.png` (iPhone 3.5-inch retina display)
- `Default-568h@2x.png` (iPhone 4-inch retina display)

Concerning other assets (actually including also launch images) you'd better use the [Asset Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html), which helps you in keeping track of assets for different resolutions.

3) [It's 120px](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html). 114px was the resolution on iOS 6 and prior versions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead Directly giving answer to you, I'll give some apple document which is most useful related to your question.
Read **[App Launch (Default) Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html)** topic in this apple's document for naming convention. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) will show you launch images size. [It](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) will show you about tabbar and Icon images size.